Dagger Hilt: Unable to resolve DefaultActivityViewModelFactory and DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory
I have errors indicate that the dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory and dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory classes are not being found on the classpath. This is likely due to missing dependencies or incorrect versions. But i do not know whitch version to input and what is a cause of the problem
libs.versions.toml
[versions]
agp = "8.5.2"
coil = "2.7.0"
glide = "4.14.2"
hiltAndroidCompiler = "2.48"
hiltLifecycleViewmodel = "1.0.0-alpha03"
kotlin = "2.0.10"
coreKtx = "1.13.1"
junit = "4.13.2"
junitVersion = "1.2.1"
espressoCore = "3.6.1"
appcompat = "1.7.0"
kotlinxCoroutinesCore = "1.8.1"
lifecycleViewmodelKtx = "2.8.4"
material = "1.12.0"
activity = "1.9.1"
constraintlayout = "2.1.4"
ksp = "2.0.10-1.0.24"
navigationFragmentKtx = "2.7.7"
navigationSafeArgs = "2.7.7"
roomRuntime = "2.6.1"
hilt = "2.48"
streamChatAndroidUiComponents = "6.4.4"
googleGmsGoogleServices = "4.4.2"
firebaseAuth = "23.0.0"

[libraries]
androidx-core-ktx = { group = "androidx.core", name = "core-ktx", version.ref = "coreKtx" }
androidx-hilt-compiler = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler", version.ref = "hiltLifecycleViewmodel" }
androidx-hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel = { module = "androidx.hilt:hilt-lifecycle-viewmodel", version.ref = "hiltLifecycleViewmodel" }
androidx-lifecycle-runtime-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelKtx" }
androidx-lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx = { module = "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx", version.ref = "lifecycleViewmodelKtx" }
androidx-navigation-fragment-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-navigation-ui-ktx = { module = "androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx", version.ref = "navigationFragmentKtx" }
androidx-room-compiler = { module = "androidx.room:room-compiler", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-ktx = { module = "androidx.room:room-ktx", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
androidx-room-runtime = { module = "androidx.room:room-runtime", version.ref = "roomRuntime" }
coil = { module = "io.coil-kt:coil", version.ref = "coil" }
glide = { module = "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide", version.ref = "glide" }
hilt-android = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }
hilt-android-compiler = { module = "com.google.dagger:hilt-android-compiler", version.ref = "hiltAndroidCompiler" }
junit = { group = "junit", name = "junit", version.ref = "junit" }
androidx-junit = { group = "androidx.test.ext", name = "junit", version.ref = "junitVersion" }
androidx-espresso-core = { group = "androidx.test.espresso", name = "espresso-core", version.ref = "espressoCore" }
androidx-appcompat = { group = "androidx.appcompat", name = "appcompat", version.ref = "appcompat" }
kotlinx-coroutines-android = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesCore" }
kotlinx-coroutines-core = { module = "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core", version.ref = "kotlinxCoroutinesCore" }
ksp = { module = "com.github.bumptech.glide:ksp", version.ref = "glide" }
material = { group = "com.google.android.material", name = "material", version.ref = "material" }
androidx-activity = { group = "androidx.activity", name = "activity", version.ref = "activity" }
androidx-constraintlayout = { group = "androidx.constraintlayout", name = "constraintlayout", version.ref = "constraintlayout" }
stream-chat-android-ui-components = { module = "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-ui-components", version.ref = "streamChatAndroidUiComponents" }
firebase-auth = { group = "com.google.firebase", name = "firebase-auth", version.ref = "firebaseAuth" }

[plugins]
android-application = { id = "com.android.application", version.ref = "agp" }
jetbrains-kotlin-android = { id = "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android", version.ref = "kotlin" }
google-devtools-ksp = { id = "com.google.devtools.ksp", version.ref = "ksp" }
androidx-navigation-safeargs-kotlin = { id = "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin", version.ref = "navigationSafeArgs" }
google-dagger-hilt-android = {id = "com.google.dagger.hilt.android", version.ref = "hilt"}
google-gms-google-services = { id = "com.google.gms.google-services", version.ref = "googleGmsGoogleServices" }

build.gradle.kts
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android) apply false
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services) apply false
}

build.gradle.kts (:app)
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.android.application)
    alias(libs.plugins.jetbrains.kotlin.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.devtools.ksp)
    alias(libs.plugins.androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.dagger.hilt.android)
    alias(libs.plugins.google.gms.google.services)
}
dependencies {

    implementation(libs.androidx.core.ktx)
    implementation(libs.androidx.appcompat)
    implementation(libs.material)
    implementation(libs.androidx.activity)
    implementation(libs.androidx.constraintlayout)
    implementation(libs.firebase.auth)
    testImplementation(libs.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.junit)
    androidTestImplementation(libs.androidx.espresso.core)

    //Stream
    implementation(libs.stream.chat.android.ui.components)
    implementation(libs.coil)

    // Architectural Components
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)

    // Room
    implementation (libs.androidx.room.runtime)
    ksp(libs.androidx.room.compiler)
    implementation (libs.androidx.room.ktx)

    // Coroutines
    implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.core)
    implementation (libs.kotlinx.coroutines.android)

    // Coroutine Lifecycle Scopes
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.lifecycle.runtime.ktx)

    // Navigation Components
    implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.fragment.ktx)
    implementation (libs.androidx.navigation.ui.ktx)

    //Dagger-Hilt
    implementation(libs.hilt.android)
    ksp(libs.hilt.android.compiler)

    implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
    ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)
    //Glide
    implementation(libs.glide)
    ksp(libs.ksp)

    //phone edit text
    implementation("com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.13.43")
}

Error message

Task :app:hiltJavaCompileDebug FAILED error: ComponentProcessingStep
was unable to process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
Dependency trace: element (CLASS):
androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule element
(METHOD):
provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<?
extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>) annotation:
@DefaultActivityViewModelFactory type (ERROR annotation type):
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
If type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have
prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is on your classpath. error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to
process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
Dependency trace: element (CLASS):
androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule element
(METHOD):
provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<?
extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>) annotation:
@DefaultActivityViewModelFactory type (ERROR annotation type):
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
If type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have
prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is on your classpath. error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to
process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.SingletonC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
Dependency trace: element (CLASS):
androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.ActivityModule element
(METHOD):
provideFactory(android.app.Activity,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<?
extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>) annotation:
@DefaultActivityViewModelFactory type (ERROR annotation type):
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory
If type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have
prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
is on your classpath. error: ComponentProcessingStep was unable to
process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
Dependency trace: element (CLASS):
androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelFactoryModules.FragmentModule element
(METHOD):
provideFactory(androidx.fragment.app.Fragment,android.app.Application,java.util.Map<java.lang.String,javax.inject.Provider<androidx.hilt.lifecycle.ViewModelAssistedFactory<?
extends androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel>>>) annotation:
@DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory type (ERROR annotation type):
dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory
If type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory'
is a generated type, check above for compilation errors that may have
prevented the type from being generated. Otherwise, ensure that type
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory'
is on your classpath. 4 errors
ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityRetainedC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.ActivityC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultActivityViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
ComponentProcessingStep was unable to process
'com.example.dreamchat.ChatApplication_HiltComponents.FragmentC'
because
'dagger.hilt.android.internal.lifecycle.DefaultFragmentViewModelFactory'
could not be resolved.
tried to change version of HiltViewModel and compiler to 1.0.0-alpha01
and it did not help.


The solution for me was to remove. Hilt ViewModel in new versions integrated into hilt dependency by default
implementation(libs.androidx.hilt.lifecycle.viewmodel)
ksp(libs.androidx.hilt.compiler)

